# SQL Server : select one of the concats on select

Tags: sql, sql-server, if-statement, concatenation

I am wondering if its possible to create select which will return different concatenated strings based on a value.... For example.

Table A has 3 columns

```
Name | Age | Gender
```

I would like to be able to do something like this

```
select 
     --if Gender = male
     concat(Name,'Tom',Gender)
     --if Gender = female
     concat(Name,'Kate',Gender)
```

Comment: Which database do you used?

Comment: You look for case .. when syntax

Comment: please provide expected output  and some sample data

Comment: Expected output would be Kowalski Tom Male -- if gender was male and Smith Kate Female -- if gender was female. and return all rows assigning Kowalski for guys, and Smith for woman

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT
    CASE WHEN Gender = 'male' THEN CONCAT(Name,'Tom',Gender)
         WHEN Gender = 'female' THEN CONCAT(Name,'Kate',Gender) END AS anyname
    // If it's Sql Server, CONCAT(Name,'Tom',Gender) can be Name + 'Tom' + Gender
    // If it's Oracle, CONCAT(Name,'Tom',Gender) can be Name || 'Tom' || Gender
FROM TableA
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `if`. Here very simple example:

```
select if(1 = 1, 'true', 'false');
```

In your case you can use nested if:

```
select
if (
    Gender = 'male',
    concat(Name,'Tom',Gender),
    if (Gender = 'female', concat(Name,'Kate',Gender), 'neither male nor female')
)
from yourTable;
```

Comment: I think you meant iif :)

Answer (score 0):

In sql server

```
select Name + case when Gender = 'male' then 'Tom' else 'Kate' end + Gender as NewColumn
from TableA
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this simple without any if or case just with selects :

```
select (select concat(Name,'Tom',Gender) as Male from table where Gender = male),(select concat(Name,'Kate',Gender) as Female from table where Gender = female) from table
```

Comment: this doesn't have any if and case statement all with selects